# trying to implement observer by using delegate i get the error : cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to the class where my delegate belong to

Tags: c#, delegates

```
// subject 
class SafeMode
{
    private bool m_enable = false;
    public bool Disable()
    {
        return m_enable;
    }

    public delegate void NotifyObserversHandler(bool _status);

    public event NotifyObserversHandler DiableCommands;

    public void Notify()
    {
        DiableCommands(m_enable);
    }
}


public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute(User i_User, string i_ButtonText, List<Photo> o_Photos);
    void DiableFunctionality();
}

// my only observer
public class MostPopularPic : ICommand
{
    public void DisableFunctionality()
    {
        m_enable = false;
    }
}


// at other form class that's where i  attach my observer to the delegate and the error occurs. 
foreach( KeyValuePair<string,ICommand> runner in tmp)
{
    ICommand curr = runner.Value;
    m_safer.DiableCommands += curr.DiableFunctionality();
    // faild to convert 'void' to  'SafeMode.NotifyObserversHandler' 
}
```

Comment: Please format your code more readably - the indentation is all over the place at the moment. You should be able to get Visual Studio (or whichever IDE you're using) to format it, then you can copy/paste it into Stack Overflow, and use Ctrl+K to adjust the indentation appropriately. Use the preview to make sure you post a question which is readable.

Answer (score 8):

Look at this statement:

```
m_safer.DiableCommands += curr.DiableFunctionality();
```

That's trying to *invoke* `curr.DiableFunctionality` and then subscribe the result of the method call to the `m_safer.DiableCommands` event.

You don't want to invoke the method now - you just want to convert the *method group* to a delegate, and subscribe that delegate. So you want:

```
m_safer.DiableCommands += curr.DiableFunctionality;
```

That will still have a problem though - your `DiableFunctionality` method is parameterless, whereas your `NotifyObserversHandler` delegate has a `bool` parameter. If you want to just ignore that parameter, you could use:

```
m_safer.DiableCommands += ignored => curr.DiableFunctionality();
```

This now uses a lambda expression which takes a single parameter (`ignored`) and ignores it, just calling `curr.DiableFunctionality()`.